# Wildfly, Ubuntu: Approach to allow public access to only one of several web applications in one application server?

Tags: security, ubuntu, configuration, wildfly, application-server

I have several web application inside a Wildfly 10 server. These applications are communicating by JSON requests to each other, but only one application, let's call it public application should be reachable from outside. All other applications should only be reachable from the public application.

for example...
This should be possible:

> Request from Internet -> public application (WAR1) -> internal application (WAR2) ->
>   Response

This should not be possible:

> Request from Internet -> internal application (WAR2)

I guess there are multiple possibilities to achieve that. Probably I could somehow identify the applications (jboss-web.xml?) and configure some virtual hosts or something like that inside Wildfly.

I guess I could also define some URL blockings with IP tables and I guess that's the safest approach with the least configuration.

I've not tried one of the above solutions since I don't know about the pitfalls right now. What I need is a safe solution. Internal WARs must not be accessed by public, or in other words: Internal WARs should ONLY be accessible by public application (WAR1). Any ideas about a safe solution?

Comment: If the communicate with json, I presume this is over http(s)? Why don't you just run different app servers? If hardware is an issue you can run both instances on the same machine either side by side or in vms using a different up in both cases. You can then be sure only one would be a accessible without more complex and potentially fragile configuration

Comment: @WillT This maybe could work. I will think about this solution.